# Hopping geodesics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, geodesics

Is there a complete metric space $X$ with the following property?

> For any pair of points $p,q\in X$ there is unique minimizing geodesic $[pq]_X$ that connects $p$ to $q$, but the map $(p,q)\mapsto [pq]_X$ is *not* continous.

**Comments**

- For sure such space cannot be compact (or proper).
- If we fix one end $p$, then there is a classical example --- the wheel; it is a unit circle with continuum of spikes from to the center $p$ to each point on the circle.
- An example of noncomplete space with this property can be constructed by starting with a long circle and applying the following construction countably many times: Given a geodesic space $X$ construct a space $X'$ where to each pair of points $p,q\in X$ such that $|p-q|_X>1$ we add a unit segment with ends in $p$ and $q$.

Comment: This is a nice question. But are not you the most qualified MO user to answer it?

Comment: This question was asked at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482311/on-continuously-uniquely-geodesic-space-ii?noredirect=1&lq=1, but the discussion was inconclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, such examples do live. The following answer was given in "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature" by Bridson and Haefliger; thanks to [GGT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654193/12434) and [Moishe Kohan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/39654/moishe-kohan).

[image]